# Angularjs Bootstrap Toggle Sidebar

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi I am using the following sidebar as my Admin dashboard.

```
<div ng-controller="VVKIController">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <span class="visible-xs">KL</span>
                <span class="hidden-xs">Kaitani Labs</span>
            </a>
            <p class="navbar-text">
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <button class="navbar-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <button class="navbar-btn" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30/people" class="img-circle">
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<article class="wrapper">

    <aside class="sidebar">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#dashboard" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> 
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#configuration" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> 
                    <span>Configuration</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#users" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i> 
                    <span>Users</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#mail" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 
                    <span>Mail</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <section class="main">

        <section class="tab-content">

            <section class="tab-pane active fade in content" id="dashboard">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                        <div class="panel panel-success">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                        <div class="panel panel-danger">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                        <div class="panel panel-warning">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Something
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                This layout uses tabs to demonstrate what you could do with it. It probably makes more sense to use individual pages/templates in a production app.
                                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Something
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                The sidebar is naturally responsive according to screen width. You can toggle it using the menu button in the topbar. Test it out by increasing/decreasing your screen width and watch it respond.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Kaitani Labs
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                Designed by <a href="http://www.kaitanilabs.com" target="_blank">Kaitani Labs</a></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </section>

            <section class="tab-pane fade" id="configuration">
                <nav class="subbar">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#access" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> <span>System</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#roles" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Roles</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <section class="tab-content content">

                    <section class="tab-pane active fade in" id="access">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        Something
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        Something
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        Something
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        Something
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                    <section class="tab-pane fade" id="roles">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        Something
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        Something
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <br/><br/><br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        Something
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <br/><br/><br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
            <section class="tab-pane fade" id="users">

            </section>
            <section class="tab-pane fade" id="mail">

            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</article>
```

I am using angularjs.I can't able to get the sidebar toggle function.The Jquery for toggle function is ,

```
$(document).on("click",".sidebar-toggle",function(){
    $(".wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

And i am new to angular js.I have included the bootstrap tls cdn.I don't know how to implement the toggle sidebar in angularjs.And i don't want to use that Jquery funtion for togglr sidebar.

Please help me to fix this.I am trying this for more than a day.

Comment: try with ui-bootstrap. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#collapse